# PHP Calendar use union or multiple query

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have two separate calendars: reservation_schedule and maintenance_schedule calendars. Reservation_schedule fetch data from reservation table and maintenance_schedule fetch data from maintenance table. My goal is to put both fetched data from the two calendars into one calendar.

Here is the query I used for the reservation_schedule:

```
SELECT acode
FROM reservation 
WHERE month(etd) = '".$month."' 
AND dayofmonth(etd) = '".$dayArray["mday"]."' 
AND year(etd) = '".$year."' 
ORDER BY etd
```

And for the maintenance_schedule:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.reg  AS 'reg', 
                    a.date AS 'date' 
    FROM   (SELECT Curdate() 
                   + INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) day AS Date 
            FROM   (SELECT 0 AS a 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 2 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 3 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 4 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 5 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 7 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 8 
                    UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a 
                   CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 2 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 3 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 4 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 5 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 7 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 8 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b 
                   CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 2 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 3 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 4 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 5 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 7 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 8 
                               UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a 
           INNER JOIN maintenance_sched s 
                   ON a.date >= s.date_from 
                      AND a.date <= s.date_to 
    WHERE  Month(date) = '".$month."' 
           AND Dayofmonth(date) = '".$dayArray["mday"]."' 
           AND Year(date) = '".$year."'
```

I can show data from both of them by using `UNION` but I want the data from the maintenance table to be outputted as string with strikethrough. I'm outputting the query result in this code:

```
$chkEvent_res = mysql_query($chkEvent_sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($chkEvent_res) > 0) {
            $event_title = "<br/>";
            while ($ev = mysql_fetch_array($chkEvent_res)) {
                $event_title .= stripslashes($ev["reg"])."<br/>";
                //$event_title .= "<del>".stripslashes($ev["acode"])."</del><br/>";
            }
            mysql_free_result($chkEvent_res);
        } else {
            $event_title = "";
        }
```

If I use the query with `UNION`, I can't set the output string from maintenance to have strikethrough since it runs the query once. How can I achieve having the fetched data from maintenance table to output with strikethrough? Should I go for the one query with `UNION`? If I do, how can I separate the data coming from maintenance table and reservation table? If I go with separating the query, how can I run it? Should it be something like `$chkEvent_res = mysql_query($chkEvent_sql1) and mysql_query($chkEvent_sql2) or die(mysql_error());`? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can `UNION` these 2 queries is if you have the same number of columns in each query, and each column have the same data type.  Not sure about the data types involved -- you have "acode" being returned from the first query and "reg" and "date" from the second query.

Assuming you could actually `UNION` your results and get what you need, you could consider adding an additional column to your results, returning the source of the query:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, 'Table1' Source
FROM TABLE1
...
UNION
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, 'Table2' Source
FROM Table2
...
```

The you could use that Source column to format your results accordingly.

Here's some additional information about using `UNION`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html